# How does the Color Keyboard app (on the App Store) change keyboard appearance?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

There is this app called "Color Keyboard" which changes the keyboard appearance for iOS. It is on the App Store. How is that possible?

How can I change the color of the keyboard in my app?

Answer (score 1):

Say you've got a `UITextField` named `myTextField`, you can use any `UIView` as your custom keyboard for this text field by setting its `inputView` property.

Thus you can create an `UIView` full of buttons, which looks like a keyboard, and attach it to your view.

This applies to any `UIResponder`, not only text fields.

Comment: True but Color Keyboard modifies the appearance on a OS level and you still have the fully fledged keyboard.

Comment: I don't think it does modify the appearance on an OS level.